# Python code to list dependencies, avoiding loops

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

Say you have a dictionary describing item dependencies, along the lines of:

```
deps = {
    'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],
    'B': ['C', 'E'],
    'C': ['D', 'F'],
    'D': ['C', 'G'],
    'E': ['A'],
    'H': ['N'],
}
```

meaning that item 'A' depends on items 'B', 'C', and 'D', etc. Obviously, this could be of arbitrary complexity.

How do you write a function `get_all_deps(item)` that gives you a list of all the dependencies of `item`, without duplicates and without `item`. E.g.:

```
> get_all_deps('H')
['N']
> get_all_deps('A')
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
> get_all_deps('E')
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G']
```

I'm looking for concise code - ideally a single recursive function. Performance is not terribly important for my use case - we're talking about fairly small dependency graphs (e.g. a few dozen items)

Comment: Oh, like the transitive closure of dependencies?

Comment: Are you aware there's a dependency cycle in your example?

Comment: @depperm I have made several attempts and have more than one working solution - all of them feel like hacks. The one I ended up using simply puts an arbitrary artificial limit on the recursion depth. There must be a better solution.

Comment: This is a graph-search problem.  You have a cyclic graph.  Again, research breadth-first search.  You might also look at Dijkstra's algorithm for a classic example of avoiding loops: you have to keep track of the nodes you've visited.

Comment: @JordanDimov The problem isn't people not reading your question, the problem is that there is an expectation (fairly standard) for you to show your attempts and where you got stuck.  Pick your "least hacky" solution and explain precisely what you think is unsuitable about it *for your purposes*.  You already said performance is not important, so having a baseline for conciseness to measure relative to is actually a critical part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a stack/todo list to avoid recursive implementation:

```
deps = {
    'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],
    'B': ['C', 'E'],
    'C': ['D', 'F'],
    'D': ['C', 'G'],
    'E': ['A'],
    'H': ['N'],
}

def get_all_deps(item):
    todo = set(deps[item])
    rval = set()
    while todo:
        subitem = todo.pop()
        if subitem != item:  # don't add start item to the list
            rval.add(subitem)
            to_add = set(deps.get(subitem,[]))
            todo.update(to_add.difference(rval))
    return sorted(rval)

print(get_all_deps('A'))
print(get_all_deps('E'))
print(get_all_deps('H'))
```

result:

```
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G']
['N']
```

`todo` set contains the elements to be processed.

- Pop one element and put it in return value list
- Loop until no more elements (okay there's a loop in here)
- add only the elements to process if they're not already in the return value.
- return sorted list

The `set` difference avoids the problem with cyclic dependencies, and the "max recursion depth" is avoided. Only limit is system memory.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was trying a recursive variant of this (e.g. passing a 'seen' set down the recursion) but not getting anywhere with it.. The stack trick is great. I'm still wondering if there's a clever way of doing this recursively.